# Line breaks when using rails console(Terminal)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, terminal

When I type large ActiveRecord queries,Before finishing the query, the line is breaking and I can't even reading or typing the command properly.I am using ubuntu.Any solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally narrowed the issue to be with resizing the terminal.Usually I maximize the terminal for typing large commands , hence the problem.
Found out that this can be solved by handling the SIGWINCH signal to resize IRB.In the solution below i am also resizing Hirb.

**Add the following lines to ~/.irbrc (create one if it doesn't exist) :**

```
Signal.trap('SIGWINCH', proc { y, x = `stty size`.split.map(&:to_i); Hirb::View.resize(x, y) if defined? Hirb } )
```

Comment: For those not using Hirb
`Signal.trap('SIGWINCH', proc { y, x = `stty size`.split.map(&:to_i); Readline.set_screen_size(y, x) if defined? Readline } )`

Answer (score 3):

A more generic way is using a `\` at the end of your line.

Using the same example of "Kenny Grant"

```
ruby> User.very.long.chain.of.arel.commands. \
      where('thing = ?', 4).very.long.chain.of.arel.commands
```

the last line should not have any ending `\` and then the whole command will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed the same bug with irb, rails console uses irb by default.
That's why I'm using pry, look [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails) how to setup pry with rails.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is like this:

```
rails c
ruby> User.very.long.chain.of.arel.commands.where('thing = ?',4).very.long.chain.of.arel.commands
```

You should be able to do this:

```
ruby> User.very.long.chain.of.arel.commands.where('thing = ?',
          4).very.long.chain.of.arel.commands
```

and split it on any commas within the conditions, then when you press return at the end it will execute.